# And in this situation can math not work?

Tags: proof-verification, fake-proofs

Imagine you need to find an unknown like the following:
using a Statement A you find a statement B (for example an equality) that let you find that unknown,but when you have statement B you dosen't always have statement A, which means Statements A and B are not equivalent,and then you find the unknown using statement B.
Will that value be correct?
for example:
You need to find coordinates of a point D, with A,B,C given points that you have ABCD is parallelogram.
You use the equality AB=DC (which is not equivalent to ABCD parallelogram) and find values of D.
Will these values mean D is a parallelogram?
and If not , how can I generally know how to get good values, does I have always to use equivalent statements?

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity....what you've written makes very little sense ("but when you have statement B you dosen't always have statement B" for example).  It would help a lot of you could provide a specific example of the logical phenomenon you seek to address.

Comment: my bad I mean you dosen't always have statement A

Comment: But that was just one problem, really the whole post is unclear.  Can you give an example of what you are thinking of?

Comment: done I gave an example

Comment: For your specific example:  No.  There are infinitely many points $D$ such that $\overline {DC}=\overline {AB}$, a whole circle's worth.  Almost none of those points define parallelograms.

Comment: so generally I need to always use equivalent statements (A<=>B)?

Comment: No, that is not generally necessary. Your error is in a different part of your method.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if statement $A$ is given,
and statement $A$ implies statement $B,$
and statement $B$ leads to a solution for the unique value or location of an unknown object, then you have solved the problem of finding the unknown assuming statement $A.$ The fact that you cannot form a chain of implications in the reverse direction is irrelevant.

An error that students often make is that they show *only* the implications in the reverse direction, that is, they start with the solution and show that it implies the given conditions, which is not a proof of any kind that the given conditions imply the solution.

In your particular example,
you have a statement, "$ABCD$ is parallelogram,"
which implies another statement, "$AB=DC$."
So far, this is fine.
If the statement $AB=DC$ then allowed you to construct the unique location of the point $D$ with no other help, then you would have a valid construction.
But the statement $AB=DC$ actually tells you only that $D$ lies somewhere on a circle whose center is $C$ and whose radius is equal to $AB.$
That is not enough information to know the coordinates of the unique point $D$ that makes $ABCD$ a parallelogram.

So in your example, your attempted construction fails, but the failure is for reasons completely different than the doubts you expressed in your question.

Comment: so is it a good way when solving a problem thinking Ok from statement A I can conclude statement B, then think for a moment does statement B implies statement A?

Comment: Or always if I get one solution that means generally my answer is fine?

Comment: Neither of those ideas is correct. If statement $A$ is the condition you were given, then _it is already given_ and it is not necessary to show that it follows from any of the other statements you make. On the other hand, it is often possible to come up with a sequence of steps to "solve" a problem such that this sequence of steps leads to a solution that is uniquely determined by those steps and is also a wrong answer.

Comment: maybe the statement A they gave me is impossible to work, like they give me a statement wich have no solutions, then I conclude from statement A. a statement B that allowed me to solve it, but statement B does not imply statement A but I got one solution:

Comment: Example:Find number x and y That x+y =1 and x-y=2 and x=y. From that statement you can solve the system x+y=1 and x-y=2 and you get x=3/2 and y =-1/2 you found a value for x and y but then you look at statement A and you see that x is equal to y

Comment: thats why I tend to always think that the statements need to be equivalent

Comment: If someone gives you a statement $A$ that is provably false, then you can logically draw any conclusions from it you want and the statement "$A$ implies my conclusion" is completely logically valid! There is a standard name for this kind of thing in logic, "ex falso quodlibet." In your arithmetic example, the combined statements $x-y=2$ and $x=y$ imply that $x=\frac32$ and that $x=17$ and that $x$ is a green monkey eating a banana. Of course in such a case you should simply point out that the given conditions are impossible and therefore there is no point in attempting to "solve" the problem.

Comment: As for always requiring statements in your proofs to be equivalent: no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no. No, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no. No.